# Is there is any chance to upload without change targetsdk in Play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm facing an issue while uploading to the play store.
This issue

> Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 31".

If Change the target SDK version some of the features are not working.

Is there any solution to upload to the play console without changing the version of the target SDK.
[image: reference]

Comment: for new apps, the min target API level is 31. More info here https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

Comment: I want to upload without changing the targetsdk. Any luck?

Comment: maybe you can ask Google an extension. more info here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878